# How to add project.lock.json file to gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying something like below:

```
#DNX
project.lock.json
```

and

```
*.lock.json
```

but it does not seem to be ignoring these files.

Comment: Is the file `project.lock.json` already tracked by `git`?

Comment: It shows up (in the list of pending changes) all the time whenever I change anything in my project and compile it. I do not want to commit them so wanted to add them to gitignore file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Is this the only file that is not ignored by git or is a general issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If file is already tracked to git, then you must first remove it(physically file must be placed out of git folder for the time), commit changes and add the file again to folder. Then git will begin ignoring it using your instruction.

Comment: Or you can leave the file where it is but remove it from the index using `git rm --cached project.lock.json`. The solution suggested by this answer works too but you still have to run either `git rm project.lock.json` or `git add project.lock.json` before committing (to put the deletion into the list of changes to be committed).

Comment: If you have several projects, use `git rm -r --cached *.lock.json` in your root (solution) directory to remove project.lock.json file in all subfolders from the index.

Answer (score 1):

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/project-json   :

> The project.lock.json file is generated in the process of restoring
>   the NuGet packages in projects that use project.json. It holds a
>   snapshot of all the information that is generated as NuGet walks the
>   graph of packages and includes the version, contents, and dependencies
>   of all the packages in your project. The build system uses this to
>   choose packages from a global location that are relevant when building
>   the project instead of depending on a local packages folder in the
>   project itself. This results in faster build performance because it's
>   necessary to read only project.lock.json instead of many separate
>   .nuspec files.
>
> The project.lock.json is automatically generated on package restore,
>   so it can be omitted from source control by adding it to .gitignore
>   and .tfignore files. However, if you include it in source control, the
>   change history will show changes in dependencies resolved over time.